# IE8 object doesnt support this action-- Breaks at input tag

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, onclick

I know this error has been put up a lot on SO before; however none of them solved my issue.

I have this form:

```
<form name="btns">
<input type="button" id="pass" value="PASS" onClick="loop('pass')"></input>
<input type="button" id="fail" value="FAIL" onClick="loop('fail')"></input>
</form>
```

And IE8 breaks at the `onClick` function, and shows `Object doesnt support this action`.

If it helps, here is the `loop` function:

```
    function loop(flag) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(formid).elements;   // formid is a global variable
        for(var i = index; i < elem.length; i++) {
            index++;
            var id = elem[i].id;
            $('#'+id).trigger('click');
            break;
        }           
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm almost positive everyone reading this is thinking, "but what do all those variables contain?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gottit!

*Probably* IE8 has `loop` as some keyword..

So when I changed the above function name to `loopa` (or something serious), it works!